# Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed'... don't work in SDK 2.1.2

Tags: facebook, titanium, titanium-mobile

I run code above with success in SDK 2.0.1.GA2 and SDK 2.1.2.GA launch error this (The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.))

```
var data = {
        message : 'Venha você também conhecer o Spllite.', 
        link : 'http://facebook.com/spllite', 
        name : 'Spllite', 
        privacy : {
            value : 'CUSTOM', 
            friends : 'SELF'
        }
    };}

Ti.Facebook.requestWithGraphPath('me/feed', data, 'POST', function(e) {
        if (e.success) {
            alert('Post enviado com sucesso');
        } else if (e.error) { // Error HERE
            Ti.API.debug('SendAdPost: '+ e.error);
            alert('Facebook indisponível no momento. Tente mais tarde.');
        } else {
            Ti.API.debug('SendAdPost: Sem resposta');
            alert('Facebook indisponível no momento. Tente mais tarde.');
        }
    });
```

Ti.API.debug(e.error);

```
[DEBUG] The operation couldn’t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)
```

Object Return

```
{

error = "The operation couldn\U2019t be completed. (facebookErrDomain error 10000.)";

graph = 1;

path = "me/feed";

source = "[object FacebookModule]";

success = 0;

type = result;
```

}

Comment: You didn't provide enough information. Please provide `data` object and `e` (the error object) dump.

Answer (score 0):

The query URI, as well as the query parameters, are Okay. Whatever is causing the problem is related to the actual `link` that you are referencing. Possibly because the `http://facebook.com/spllite` page is not made public.

Comment: I think you need to specify that domain (spllite.com) in facebook app settings